# How does a JWT token with an empty payload work?

Tags: oauth, jwt

I'm working with the Snapchat API to try and log into an app using their OAuth flow. Once the user is logged in via Snapchat, I'm trying to reverse engineer (since they have no documentation on this) how to obtain some sort of unique ID for the user so I can associate them with a local user in my database. This is how I have previously done this with things like Facebook. The user logs in and gets an access token via the Facebook Api, and I can extract some kind of unique ID for the user via the Facebook API.

The Snapchat API only allows you to access the user's display name and some "externalId", which I cannot guarantee won't change. So I decoded the JWT token that Snapchat issued to me and it challenged my understanding of how JWT tokens work. When I decoded the token at http://jwt.io, I saw that the payload was empty, yet the token works when calling the https://kit.snapchat.com/v1/me endpoint. How is the snapchat server able to identify who I am? I've always had the understanding that the JWT must include a claim such as `sub` which identifies the user. The server can then use that information to know who I am.

In this case, my JWT payload is empty, but the aforementioned endpoint still returns my user data. What is happening here? How does the server know who I am when my JWT token has an empty payload? To me they must be storing a copy of my JWT token on the server, which seems like the incorrect way to use JWT tokens. Perhaps my understanding is terribly wrong. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

The payload of a JWS (signed token) can be detached and transmited to the audience by other means.

This feature is described in the [Appendix F](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#appendix-F) of the specification.

With the JWS compact serialization mode (the most common format), a token looks like `THE_HEADER.THE_PAYLOAD.THE_SIGNATURE`. With a detached payload it is identical except that `THE_PAYLOAD` is an empty string: `THE_HEADER..THE_SIGNATURE`.

The verification of the signature is the same as with an attached payload. The receiver should have received the payload and must recreate the full input i.e. `THE_HEADER.THE_PAYLOAD`.

Regarding the identification performed by snapshat, a reference to the detached payload may be set in a header parameter of the token (first part of the token) allowing Snapchat to fully verify the token.

Comment: I was using Postman and hitting the endpoint with only the same JWT that I had decoded that didn't have a payload. I sent no additional information in the HTTP request.

Comment: I meant in the header of the token, not the one of the request.